# Network share visible only to administrator?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share

On a windows server 2008 R2 machine, I would like to map a network share visible only to administrator, not to normal users that login using remote desktop. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't understand. You want to map a network share for the administrator only? Then only map it for the administrator.

Comment: Do you want to create a network share or map one?  What do the shares have to do with remote desktop users?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I thought that mapping a network share appears to all users, not only to the one that created the mapped drive. However I do not understand the negative rating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapped drives are per user.  So all you need to do is map it normally.

Answer (score 1):

You mean map a hidden share?  Or map drive only for admins?

You could use a logon script for either in group policy, and set it to apply to the administrator group only.